# Access VBA Transfer data between two database

Tags: vba, ms-access, transfer

I would like to transfer some records of a table from one Mysql DB to another(2 different IP addresses). I have both DB's connected via ODBC and the two tables as table link in my Access DB.

```
currentdb.execute "insert into Table_DB1 (col1,col2,col3) select col1, col2, col3 from Table_DB1 where col3 between #2020/01/01 0:00:00# and #2020/01/02 23:59:59#"
```

There is an index on col3 of Table_DB1 and only 60k records of this selection. But it is either very slow or Access stops responding.Is there a faster way of transferring data between 2 remote DB's in Access VB ?

Comment: Take your source data to CSV extension, copy to destination server and use CSV data as input to 2 remote destinations MySQL DB's using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ..... technique.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but we have no right to save anything on the source server

Comment: Take your source data to CSV extension on your local PC, then use fully pathed local CSV data as input to 2 remote destinations MySQL DB's using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ..... technique.  This concept might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created ADODB connection and recordset for both source and destination tables as below. The speed of transfer is acceptable.

```
Dim Con_Dest As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Con_Sour As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs_Sour As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Rs_Dest As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim Str_SqlSour As String
Dim Str_SqlDest As String

Dim Str_Sql As String

Con_Sour.Open "dsn=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx"
Con_Dest.Open "dsn=yyy;uid=yyy;pwd=yyy"

Str_SqlSour = "select * from Table_Source"

Rs_Sour.Open Str_SqlSour, Con_Sour
Rs_Dest.Open "Table_Dest", Con_Dest, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

Rs_Sour.MoveFirst
Do Until Rs_Sour.EOF

    With Rs_Dest
        .AddNew

        .Fields("AAA").Value = Rs_Sour.Fields("Col1")
        .Fields("AAB").Value = Rs_Sour.Fields("Col2")
        .....

        .Update
    End With

    Rs_Sour.MoveNext
Loop
```